# Accessing to the notifications when I click them

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have an Android application which gets notifications. When the user clicks any of them, he' is always going to be redirected to the same Activity. In this activity, I check a parameter (with this parameter I have to do a query to the server) which I have saved when I got the notification.

The problem it's that the Activity is the same, so, I save the parameter with the same key and I only have an key which it's being override again and again, kept the last value of the last notification. So, any notification that I press, it's going to get the value of the last last came. Could I save all of them with the same name with some trick? of I could have access to the message just when the user click on it?

```
                    String room = intent.getExtras().getString(ConstantsGCM.GCM_ROOM);
                    notif = new Notification(icon, textStatus, time);
                    notIntent = new Intent(contexto,GameMainActivity.class);
                    notIntent.putExtra(ConstantsRooms.ROOM, room); --> parameter that I need in the GameMainActivity.               
                    contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(contexto, 0, notIntent, 0);               
                    notif.setLatestEventInfo(contexto, tittle, description, contIntent);

                    //AutoCancel: cuando se pulsa la notificaiÛn Èsta desaparece
                    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

                    notManager.notify((int)(Math.random()*10000), notif);
```

Another question, it's, if I don't want to update the notifications, is it mandatory to give an ID in the notify method?

Comment: I'm afraid that if you use the same ID in a notificaction it will get updated and you only will see the last one, and then by clicking it you will have the last information you passed on it. You can if you want use different ids for them.

Comment: I'm using differents ID's. notManager.notify((int)(Math.random()*10000), notif); The problem is that all of them go to the same Activity, I need a data in this activity which I'm saving when I get the notification. So, I'd like that depeding which notification clicks, the activity get the data that I saved with that notification, not with the last one.